# Only allow a specific page to be iframed using Content-Security-Policy

Tags: iframe, http-headers

Is it possible to only allow a specific url on my website (any page that starts with `https://example.com/movie/**` to be iframed by others using Content-Security-Policy, and block all my other pages from being iframed?

I don't care **who** is iframing, but I care **what** is being iframed.

I only found ways to whitelist the websites that are iframing (e.g. using `frame-ancestors`), and not a way to whitelist the pages that are being iframed.

Is this at all possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the x-frame-options header in your response using DENY where you don't want pages to be framed.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use different Content Security Policies for your pages.

The pages that you don't want to be iframed should include a `frame-ancestors: none` in their returned `Content-Security-Policy` header.

The pages that you want to be iframed should return a different `Content-Security-Policy` header, using something like `frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.org https://example.com https://store.example.com;`, containing the list of websites that you want to allow iframing the page.